# How to get faster create table output in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My code takes 15 minutes to run when run as select *
But when i add create table as to it it takes 70 minutes to run.

My dataset is huge which is 48 million rows and 50 columns.

Is there an efficient way to create table in oracle

Comment: Are the query plans different?  For the `select`, are you measuring the time required to fetch the first row?  Or to fetch the last row?

Comment: You are probably measuring the performance of the query itself based on when the first row returns.  The `create table` only returns when the last row returns.

Answer (score 0):

It takes longer with a create table as it has to do more than just query.  It also has to create a table and then copy the data over to the new table.  If you do a normal create table, you can then run as a separate statements an insert or merge, or do some parallel inserts, but its unlikely you will get better performance.  Copying 48 million rows with 50 columns is intensive.